# Escape of fast moving neutrons in nuclear reactor

Tags: nuclear-physics, neutrons

My book says, in a nuclear reactor, the fast moving neutrons(possessing MeV of energy) will escape if the moderator won't  be there(in the core).That's it. It isn't elaborated there. My question is **HOW** do they escape? what's the escape route?

Answer (score 2):

The neutrons are just bouncing around, hitting nuclei, bouncing off elastically, being absorbed, or most importantly, causing fission in a fuel nucleus.

But there is nothing **confining** these neutrons; they are free to carry out their random walk and leave the confines of the reaction zone.  They just need to be lucky enough to miss being absorbed or causing fission before finding the edge of the reaction zone.

In the simplest type of uncontrolled nuclear reaction, you start with a hemisphere of, say $U_{235}$.  The lump is small enough that the probable number of new neutrons created by one existing neutron as it traverses the lump, and eventually exits, is less than one.

Nothing much happens in this lump, principally because any stray neutron entering into (or appearing in) the lump has a high probability of shooting out of the lump before it has a chance to multiply itself.

Simple physics says half these exiting neutrons will leave through the hemisphere's flat surface.

Now, take that other similar hemisphere over there, and  **slam** the two together into a sphere.

Now, those neutrons that were escaping, "leaking" out of each of the lumps, now finds itself in an identical lump.  Those neutrons now have more opportunities to cause fission, and, as long as you can hold the two hemispheres together, the neutron count, and the energy release rate will increase.

Google "twisting the dragon's tail" or "demon core" for some accidents that arose from a different way of "saving" lost neutrons...

Answer (score 0):

Neutrons interact with the nuclei of the surrounding medium as they move.  If absorbed, they disappear, but may result in more neutrons being produced if the absorption reaction is fission, or some weird reaction such as n-2n (such as 14 MeV neutrons interacting with lead).  If they scatter they are reduced in energy but continue to move throughout the medium.  If they are not ultimately absorbed in the medium, they "leak" (escape) the medium.  After escaping the medium they may scatter back into the medium especially if a reflector is used. The transport equation is used to model this behavior; this is a complicated integro-differential equation.  Under certain conditions, a simplification of the transport equation called the diffusion equation is applicable.